# How to open file name contain special characters in FFmpeg?

Tags: c++, video, stream, ffmpeg, video-streaming

my project process the video by FFmpeg libarary, I test the my code with file which the file name contains special characters(like '**()+,-.09@A[]^_`a{}~®,Ѐ,ऄ, ఆ, Ⴀ,ᐁ,ᣀ,ᴀ,₠,⓪,⭙,ⶀ,㈀,啊.mp4**'), but it failed to open the video stream at **avformat_open_input()**.

I test it via **ffmpeg.exe** with command line, it can open the file successfully.

This is my code snippet:

```
    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
    AVCodecContext  *pCodecCtx = NULL;
    AVFrame         *pFrameRGB = NULL;
    unsigned int    i, videoStream;
    AVCodec         *pCodec;
    AVFrame         *pFrame;
    AVPacket        packet;
    int             frameFinished;
    int             numBytes;
    uint8_t         *buffer;
    AVPixelFormat   ImgFmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

    // Register all formats and codecs
    av_register_all();

    // Open video file
    if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, inputFilePath, NULL, NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("Couldn't open file.");
        return -1;
    }
```

it occur error at the **avformat_open_input()**, I think it failed because of the Unicode file name string

Anybody can help me?

Thanks

Comment: `0`, `9` and `A` are *special characters*? I must be getting old.

Comment: @KerrekSB, Hi, what i mean is contains special character, not all of them, thanks

Comment: Have you tried just plain file I/O and made sure that works as expected? Maybe the problem has nothing to do with ffmpeg.

Comment: @KerrekSB, of course, it works well on file with normal file name but this

Comment: No, I meant does normal file I/O (`fopen`) work with *this filename*. Make sure that it's not a problem with the file system rather than with ffmpeg.

Comment: @KerrekSB, yes, I can open and play the video with Video player, so there is no problem with the video stream and I/O

Comment: true, you should be able to first check with special character files names and try to read them with normal file i/o. should be some utf-8 issue i think.

Comment: @KerrekSB, but I can open it via ffmpeg.exe with command line, and process the video, I don't know why